# How to inject an implementation in an injection point whose type is an interface

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Suppose I have the following interface:

```
public interface Interface1 {
}
```

and the following class:

```
public class Class1 implements Interface1 {}
```

Also, I have this class:

```
public class Class2 {
    private Interface1 interface;
    public void setInterface(Interface1 interface) {
        this.interface = interface;
    }
}
```

What should I put in my `applicationContext.xml` to inject a bean generated by `Class1` into `Class2.interface`? Also, is it possible to do it with annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just inject it like any other bean, as long as the Runtime types are compatible it will work fine, there's no need to do anything special with the interface type in your XML.

```
<bean id="class1" class="package.Class1"/>
<bean id="class2" class="package.Class2">
  <property name="interface" ref="class1"/>
</bean>
```

`@Autowired` will also work fine, of course if there is more than one implementation of interface1 in the container, you will want to specify a bean name with `@Qualifier`.

Answer (score 1):

- if you use xml it wouldn't matter - you define your bean and you inject your bean by bean name (rather than type)
- if you use annotations, use can use `@Resource(name="beanName")` or a `@Qualifier`

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is javaconfig:

```
package com.mycom.myapp.config;

@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public Class1 class1() {
    return new Class1();
  }

  @Bean
  public Class2 class2() {
    Class2 class2 = new Class2();
    class2.setInterface(class1());
  }
}
```

And then another tiny bit of xml glue code to get the xml config to find your
@Configuration annotated classes.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycom.myapp.config" />
```

When it sees the @Configuration, it automatically does some spring magic, and uses that class to construct your beans, and makes them available to the rest of the Xml based context, so you could mix and match if you wanted.  It's smart enough to deal with bean scopes, proxying, etc.... even when you call a method local to that class (like "class1()" in the above example) thanks to some nifty javassist magic.

For more info, see:  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java